# CSS table column rules

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS shorthand which I can use to exclude a table's first and second column from this rule?

```
th.header {
        background-image: url(../static/images/bg.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right center;
    }
```

I think I need the column equivalent of something like: `tr:not(.firstrow)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the cells in question do not span more than one column (i.e. do not have a `colspan` that isn't 1), you can use `:nth-child()`.

You can either exclude each column individually:

```
th.header:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    background-image: url(../static/images/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Or, if the columns to exclude are consecutive and you want to start from, say, the third column, use `:nth-child()` with the formula `n+b` where `b` is the column you want to start with:

```
th.header:nth-child(n+3) {
    background-image: url(../static/images/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Comment: Was going to add an answer to cover the `:nth-child(n+3)` option, but your edit beat me to it.